# Validar un formato de fecha y hora con expresón regular

Tags: regex

Estoy intentando validar este formato de fecha y hora en plsql:

```
Tue Nov 22 23:40:36 2022
```

De la siguiente manera, pero no lo hace:

```
^[A-z]\s[A-z]\s[0-9]\s[-.:0-9]\s20[0-9]{2}+$
```

Alguien me puede ayudar a ver mi error?

Answer (score 0):

Podría ser algo como esto:

```js
let regex = /^([A-Z][a-z]{2} ){2}[0-3][0-9] [0-2][0-9](:[0-6][0-9]){2} 20[0-9]{2}$/g


pruebas = [
"Tue Nov 22 23:40:36 2022" ,
"Tue Nov 22 37:40:36 2022", // hora muy grande
"Tue Nov 22 23:40:36 1122", // año menor al 2000
"Tue nov 22 23:40:36 2022", // minuscula
"Tue nov 22 23:60:36 2022", // minutos muy grande
"Asd Asd 45 21:21:34 2032", // Dia muy grande
"AsdAsd 45 21:21:34 2032"]; // Espacio

for (let p of pruebas) {
    console.log(p, !(p.match(regex) == null));
}
```

Además incluí pequeñas validaciones, que no son 100% precisos pero que pueden ayudar, como por ejemplo el día no puede ser mayor a 39